# Checking software requirements

Tags: tdd, srs

As part of a homework assignment, I have to check an SRS (Software Requirement Specification) document for mistakes. One of the chapters look like this:

> 4 - Verification
>
> The current specification of the system will be
>   inspected by an external team of experts.
>
> Unit tests and integration tests must be used to verify the system.
>   The system will be developed partly by TDD method.

My problem is the last sentence. Does that even make sense? To develop something partly by TDD? I have to give a reason for everything, and I don't know how to explain this one: is it plain nonsense, or it's sensible, but not a full definition (what part is TDD? what happens to the other parts?).

Thanks in advance,
Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDD (Test Driven Development) is a development process such that developers write tests that their future code will have to pass. It provides guidelines that the developer has to follow to pass the tests.

Back to the question, it sounds like to me that there is a current system in place in which experts are going to inspect. Then afterwards for future development (in which this RS was written for) they are going to use TDD; unit tests and integration tests are part of TDD. So I think this makes sense but I would spend a little time reading about TDD.

Comment: Thank you, I was also thinking about the same thing.